# Django CBV with custom decorator

Tags: python, django, permissions, decorator

I'm trying to create a custom access permission base on where does my staff work. For example if they're working at clinic A, they can only view/add/modify data for that clinic A. But if they're incharge of that district, they can access all those clinic in that district. It work fine on function base view but its killing me on class base view. So far my code as follow :

```
def restrict_klinik(function):
def wrapper(request,slug, *args, **kw):
    klinikslug = request.user.letakstaf_set.filter(klinik__slug=slug).count()
    retenslug = Reten.objects.filter(slug=slug).count()
    rejectslug = Reject.objects.filter(slug=slug).count()

    if klinikslug == 1 or retenslug == 1 or rejectslug == 1:
        return function(request, slug, *args, **kw)

    messages.error(request, 'Sorry, You dont have access.') 
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('home'))
return wrapper

class RestrictKlinikMixin(views.LoginRequiredMixin):
    @method_decorator(restrict_klinik)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(RestrictKlinikMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm using @restrict_klinik for my function base view, but I got problem when using class base view, eg :

class AddClinic(RestrictKlinikMixin, generic.CreateView):

it will throw 'slug' error.
any ideas? Thanks!

**UPDATE**:
 Apparently 1 of my views using kwargs['slug'] instead of self.kwargs['slug']. Funny that the only thing I've changed is adding that new mixin in my views. Wasted like 4 hours figuring this one out as it has been working fine for 1 month with just using kwargs['slug'].

Comment: Can you show me full error?

Comment: apparently I used kwargs['slug'] instead of self.kwargs['slug'] in one of my views.. fixed it..but funny that it works before.

Comment: Write and accept your own answer rather than adding SOLVED to the title. It helps other people with similar problems.

Comment: thanks..will do (need 2 days to accept my own question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently 1 of my views using kwargs['slug'] instead of self.kwargs['slug']. Funny that the only thing I've changed is adding that new mixin in my views. Wasted like 4 hours figuring this one out as it has been working fine for 1 month with just using kwargs['slug'].